# Get the date from online in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, date

I'm using [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)to get the date on an [html](/questions/tagged/html)page, but the page gets the date from the computer. I want the page to display the correct date, even if the one on the computer is wrong. Currently I'm using this:

```
var now2 = new Date();
```

For example, if the date were set to `July 28th 14:00` on the computer, I still want the page to say `December 5th 15:52`.

Comment: you can make an ajax request to your server and show the response

Comment: What if the user has changed the timezone on their computer?

Comment: https://www.programmableweb.com/category/time/api

Comment: You need retrieve the date from a server or set the date with a specific timezone use this question to get an idea: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087819/convert-date-to-another-timezone-in-javascript